# Secure Android POST Data to Web Server API from Packet Capture APP

Tags: android, post, encryption

First I'm sorry for my bad English.
I'm currently developing android application that require user login from existing database on the web server and the application is working smoothly, but when I tried to trace the data packets sent through my application using the Packet Capture App from Google Play, the password data sent by My application is plain text (unencrypted). I tried using base64 encoded to encrypt the password but base64 is very common and easy to decode, my question is :
1. is there another way to secure (encrypt) data (username,passwords,etc) that sent from android application to PHP on web server?
2. when using the application Packet Capture, I saw another well-known applications such as Facebook, BBM, etc. displays "No Data" on the packet capture application, how do I do that?

NB:
Packet Capture link is here:
play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture

Here is my doInBackground in login class :

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String url = "http://mydomainhost.com/login.php?" +
                 "username="+ username.getText().toString() +
                 "&password="+ password.getText().toString() + "&imei=" + imei;
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        try {
            success = json.getString("sukses");
            pesan = json.getString("pesan");

            Log.e("error", "nilai sukses=" + success);

            JSONArray hasil = json.getJSONArray("login");

            if (success.equals("1")) {

                for (int i = 0; i < hasil.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = hasil.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id").trim();
                    String username = c.getString("username").trim();
                    String nama = c.getString("nama").trim();
                    String email = c.getString("email").trim();
                    String som_id = c.getString("som_id").trim();
                    gcm_regid = c.getString("gcm_regid").trim();
                    session.createLoginSession(id, username, nama, email, imei, som_id, gcm_regid);
                    Log.e("ok", " ambil data");

                }
            } else {
                Log.e("erro", "tidak bisa ambil data 0");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error", "tidak bisa ambil data 1");
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Here is PHP to receive login class :

```
$pass_acak = generateHash($password,'yr');
$username   = strtolower($username);
$sql_cek = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$pass_acak' LIMIT 1";
$qry_cek = mysql_query($sql_cek);
$dt=mysql_fetch_array($qry_cek);
$ada_cek = mysql_num_rows($qry_cek);
if ($ada_cek >=1) {
    if($dt['status']==0){
        $respon['sukses']=0;
        $respon['pesan']="Username ".$username." Tidak Aktif!";
    } else {
        if($imei==$dt['imei']){
            $respon['sukses']=1;
            $respon['pesan']="Login Berhasil";
            $h['id']=$dt['id'];
            $h['username']=$username;
            $h['email']=$dt['email'];
            $h['nama']=$dt['nama'];
            $h['som_id']=$dt['som_id'];
            $h['imei']=$dt['imei'];
            $h['gcm_regid']=$dt['gcm_regid'];
            $respon['login'][]=$h;
        } else {
            $respon['sukses']=0;
            $respon['pesan']="IMEI tidak cocok!";
        }
    }
} else {
    $respon['sukses']=0;
    $respon['pesan']="Username / Password Salah!";
}
```

NB: generateHash is my own function to generate encrypted password

Here is Packet Capture Result from My App :

```
POST /login.php?username=anggazan&
password=mypassword&imei=01234567890123456 HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Host: mydomainhost.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 336
Date: Sat, 30 Jan 2016 15:48:02 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close

{"sukses":1,"pesan":"Login Sukses"}
```

NB: I'm Sorry, I change my real password to "mypassword" and my real imei to "01234567890123456" for privacy use.

[Here is Packet Capture look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1qJ6.png), My App Name is TSMobile Semarang thre is show that my app sent 778B data but the other app like facebook, xiaomi and any google app display "No Data".

And [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMZ6A.png) is what look like when i click facebook app with "No Data" and SSL symbol in Packet Capture APP. It's look that facebook encrypted their data, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use HTTPS instead of plain HTTP, your data is already encrypted.

The app you mention performs a man in the middle attack, if you install this app you are deliberatly saying it should decrypt your data. If your TLS client is configured in a way that it accepts the connection, there is little you can do about it.

I also doubt that facebook uses additional encryption, my guess would be it is just gziped or otherwise encoded content.

Of course you can encrypt everything end to end, but then you have to show us what you already tried, show us code.

Comment: Hi...thanks for your answer...https is not solve the problem...i have other app that use https connection but packet capture app can read the data in plain text but with encrypted password, i will update captured data with https soon...

Comment: hi...I have added my code...how do I use gzip or encode when i sent my POST data on my app?

Comment: Yes, i use HTTP because i use shared hosting that not support HTTPS...what is the best solution if i just want to secure the password that sent from my app to PHP on web server?my idea is i encode the password on my app and decode it on my PHP but i don't know how to do it...i'm sorry if i ask much question because i'm very beginner with java...

Comment: Well, I already put that in my answer, you can encrypt it on your own. (Note: better use the term encryption, not encoding). But you have to start finding the solution on your own, if you encounter problems, you may ask here. It doesn't matter that you don't know Java, which languages do you know? The architecture would be the same, you just have to find the corresponding language constructs and libraries. But the answer to your question stays the same: Use HTTPS! That's not gonna change. If it's critical, use HTTPS! There's no excuse.